# pytest conforms to naming convention but not collecting tests and results in no tests ran

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest, appium-ios, python-appium

Whenever I try to run `pytest test_clientLogin.py`, it results in collecting 0 items and no tests ran despite my module and method conforming to pytest default naming convention as far as I know. Am I missing something here?

```
import unittest
import os
from random import randint
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Test_ClientLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app = ('/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-adbzyybfvvcneaboeastjqennmqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appName.app')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'app': app,
                 'platformName': 'iOS',
                  'platformVersion': '12.1',
                  'deviceName': 'iPhone 8'
                }
        )

        def test_emailField(self):
            el1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"appName\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTextField")
            el1.send_keys("myEmail@gmail.com")
            sleep(1)
            self.assertNotEqual(el1.get_attribute("value"), "myEmail@gmail.com")

        def test_passwordField(self):
            el2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"appName\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField")
            el2.send_keys("myPassword")
            sleep(1)
            self.assertNotEqual(el2.get_attribute("value"), "myPassword")

        def test_login(self):
                self.test_emailField()
                self.test_passwordField()
                el3 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Log In")
                el3.click()
                sleep(1)
                smiley = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar[@name="Journal"]""")
                self.assertNotEqual(smiley.get_attribute("name"), "Journal")

        def tearDown(self):
                self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test_ClientLogin)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)`
```

Comment: Can you try renaming your class name to Testlogin or TestLogin and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import os
from random import randint
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class TestClientLogin():

    def setUp(self):
        app = ('/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-adbzyybfvvcneaboeastjqennmqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appName.app')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'app': app,
                 'platformName': 'iOS',
                  'platformVersion': '12.1',
                  'deviceName': 'iPhone 8'
                }
        )

        def test_email_field(self):
            el1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"appName\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTextField")
            el1.send_keys("myEmail@gmail.com")
            sleep(1)
            self.assertNotEqual(el1.get_attribute("value"), "myEmail@gmail.com")

        def test_password_field(self):
            el2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"appName\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField")
            el2.send_keys("myPassword")
            sleep(1)
            self.assertNotEqual(el2.get_attribute("value"), "myPassword")

        def test_login(self):
                self.test_emailField()
                self.test_passwordField()
                el3 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Log In")
                el3.click()
                sleep(1)
                smiley = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar[@name="Journal"]""")
                self.assertNotEqual(smiley.get_attribute("name"), "Journal")

        def tearDown(self):
                self.driver.quit()
```

Run `pytest test_clientLogin.py`